# MS SQL Server: Operate current select values in other selected columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I want to take a value from a selected column to operate the next column. For example:

```
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN ID < 4 THEN ID
  ELSE 10
END
AS MY_ID,
MY_ID + 5 AS EXTRA_ID
FROM FOO
```

That would output for IDs `1,2,3,4,5`:

```
MY_ID EXTRA_ID
1      6
2      7
3      8
10     15
10     15
```

If I do `MY_ID + 5` it will complain about MY_ID not existing (it's an alias, so it makes sense) and `ID + 5` will read `1+5, 2+5, 3+5, 4+5, 5+5` instead of `1+5, 2+5, 3+5, 4+10, 5+10` when it goes through the ELSE. Is it even possible to do this? I'm doing it in SSRS - Report builder, and need to operate a result that might be set to a defualt value depending on the CASE clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can repeat the same CASE expression with +5 in the end for the extra_id column

```
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN ID < 4 THEN ID
  ELSE 10
END
AS MY_ID,
CASE 
  WHEN ID < 4 THEN ID
  ELSE 10
END + 5 AS EXTRA_ID
FROM FOO
```

An alternative is to create the extra_id column value inside SSRS using an expression

`= Fields!my_id.value + 5`

Comment: I just wanted to clarify the other answers are also correct, but this one is the simplest and provides an example for the solution. It was really simple, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you cannot reuse the calculation in the same level. Using my_id in the where clause will fail as well. Either you have to calucate it multiple times, place another select around your statement or use a with statement (CTE).

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap it with another select:

```
SELECT t.*,
       t.my_id + 5 as extra_id
FROM(Your Query) t
```

Derived columns are not available in the same layer they're being created. By wrapping them with another select, you make them available (that because the inner query is being processed before the outer) .

Answer (score 0):

You just need a subquery to create `MY_ID` before doing anything with it.  By creating `MY_ID` in the inner query the outer query can use to define new fields.

```
SELECT 
    a.MY_ID, 
    a.MY_ID + 5 AS EXTRA_ID
from
    (SELECT 
        CASE 
          WHEN ID < 4 THEN ID
          ELSE 10
        END
        AS MY_ID
    FROM FOO) as a
```